# Is it correct to start a sentence with "with" in English?

Tags: prepositions, word-order, syntactic-analysis, sentence-starts, redundancy

Is it correct to use *with* at the beginning of a sentence?

Here's an example sentence:

> With the development of the economy, living standards improved.

To my eyes this looks unnatural; I would rewrite it thus:

> Living standards have improved as a result of economic development.

I think it sounds better because, as I understand it, in English it is more natural to put the result at the beginning of the sentence, and then the contributing factors or background information after that. But I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Just as an aside, there are **no** rules saying "You can't start an English sentence with `insert word`". None at all. Languages don't work that way, and certainly English doesn't. Language is not just a big bag of words.

Comment: *Original sentence* - with no corn to sell this year, how will we earn a living? 
*Modified sentence* - due to no corn to sell this year, how will we earn a living? *Modified sentence* because of no corn to sell this year, how will we earn a living? 

are they all same?

Answer (score 8):

There's nothing grammatically wrong with that construction. In fact it's quite common. It's an example of a [*dependent clause*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_clause). You can use any [*subordinating conjunctions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_%28grammar%29#Subordinating_conjunctions) in this way.

However, I will agree that it sounds a bit odd for other reasons. *The development of the economy* speaks of the development almost as if it was a single event. Personally, I'd write it like this:

> With the developing economy, living standards improved.

Comment: Yes - the grammar's fine either way, but I prefer 'as a result of economic development' to 'with the development of the economy' on semantic grounds.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: *Original sentence* - with no corn to sell this year, how will we earn a living? 
*Modified sentence* - due to no corn to sell this year, how will we earn a living? *Modified sentence* because of no corn to sell this year, how will we earn a living? 

are they all same?

Comment: @Pankaj Late response, I know, but the original sentence definitely sounds more natural to me. "due to", and "because of" are somewhat formal constructions, but the following clause, "how will we earn a living?" is more informal. So the mix of the two tones comes across as quite awkward. I'd recommend considering what overall tone you're trying to convey and trying to be consistent throughout.